# CMake fails to find boost libraries (CGAL, Windows)

Tags: c++, boost, build, cmake, cgal

I saw dozens of identical questions about this issue. None of their answers worked for me I'm afraid.

I'm trying to install CGAL. I'm following the [following tutorial](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/setup-cgal-in-windows-7-step-by-step-tutorial/) describing the process step-by-step. The only difference is that I'm using CodeBlocks and I've selected "Specify native compilers" and pointed them to `mingw32-gcc.exe` and `mingw32-g++.exe` which seems to be fine. When I run cmake-gui and then click configure, I get the following output, with the Advanced option ticked:

```html
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.4.1
The C compiler identification is GNU 4.4.1
Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Check for working C compiler: E:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/mingw32-gcc.exe
Check for working C compiler: E:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/mingw32-gcc.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
== Setting paths ==
Build CGAL from release in directory CGAL-4.6
Packagenames: CGAL-4.6
== Setting paths (DONE) ==

== Generate version files ==
CGAL_MAJOR_VERSION=4
CGAL_MINOR_VERSION=6
CGAL_BUGFIX_VERSION=0
CGAL_SONAME_VERSION=11
CGAL_SOVERSION     =11.0.0
CGAL_REFERENCE_CACHE_DIR=
Building shared libraries
Targetting MinGW Makefiles
Using E:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe compiler.
USING CMake version: 2.8.8
System: Windows
USING GCC_VERSION = '4.4.1'
Using gcc version 4 or later. Adding -frounding-math
== Generate version files (DONE) ==

== Set up flags ==
Build type: Release
USING CXXFLAGS = ' -frounding-math -O3 -DNDEBUG'
USING LDFLAGS = '  '
== Set up flags (DONE) ==

== Detect external libraries ==
External libraries supported: GMP;MPFR;ZLIB;OpenGL;LEDA;MPFI;RS;RS3;OpenNL;Eigen3;BLAS;LAPACK;QGLViewer;ESBTL;Coin3D;NTL;IPE
Preconfiguring library: GMP ...
Found GMP: e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/CGAL-4.6/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.dll  
GMP has been preconfigured:
  UseGMP-file:      
  GMP include:      e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/CGAL-4.6/auxiliary/gmp/include
  GMP libraries:    e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/CGAL-4.6/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.dll
  GMP definitions:  
USING GMP_VERSION = '5.0.1'
Preconfiguring library: MPFR ...
Found MPFR: e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/CGAL-4.6/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.dll  
MPFR has been preconfigured:
  UseMPFR-file:      
  MPFR include:      e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/CGAL-4.6/auxiliary/gmp/include
  MPFR libraries:    e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/CGAL-4.6/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.dll
  MPFR definitions:  
USING MPFR_VERSION = '3.0.0'
CMake Error at E:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1200 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.58.0

  Boost include path: e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/boost_1_58_0

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_thread
          boost_system

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupBoost.cmake:6 (find_package)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:85 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:640 (include)


Boost include:     e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/boost_1_58_0
Boost libraries:   
Boost definitions: 
USING BOOST_VERSION = '1.58.0'
== Detect external libraries (DONE) ==

== Write compiler_config.h ==
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_BOOST_VARIANT_SWAP_BUG - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_DENORMALS_COMPILE_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_FPU_ROUNDING_MODE_UNWINDING_VC_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_IEEE_754_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_ISTREAM_INT_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_5 - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_6 - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_7 - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_8 - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NESTED_CLASS_FRIEND_DECLARATION_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_LIMITS - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_NEXTAFTER - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_STL - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_WARNING_CPP_DIRECTIVE_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NUMERIC_LIMITS_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_OUTOFLINE_MEMBER_DEFINITION_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_TEMPLATE_IN_DEFAULT_PARAMETER_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_TYPENAME_BEFORE_DEFAULT_ARGUMENT_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_USING_BASE_MEMBER_BUG_2 - Success
== Write compiler_config.h (DONE) ==

== Generating build files ==
Configuring libCGAL
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Core' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Core
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_Core is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_ImageIO' detected
Configuring libCGAL_ImageIO
Found OpenGL: opengl32  
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
OpenGL include:     
OpenGL libraries:   glu32;opengl32
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_ImageIO is configured
NOTICE: libCGAL_ImageIO needs ZLib to read compressed files. That feature will not be activated.
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt3' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Qt3
libCGAL_Qt3 needs Qt3, cannot be configured.
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt4' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Qt4
libCGAL_Qt4 needs Qt4, cannot be configured.
Sources for CGAL component libraries 'CGAL_Core;CGAL_ImageIO;CGAL_Qt3;CGAL_Qt4' detected
== Generating build files (DONE) ==

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I did indeed setup `BOOST_ROOT` to a PATH in CMake's GUI, to `e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/boost_1_58_0`, which exists. And the two libraries it mentions are definitely installed. I've noticed there's no explicit include folder in my boost installation (though their is libs). I've tried checking the CGAL_Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS option with no better results. What is happening here? What do I need to do?

Comment: You need the boost includes if you want to use the boost library in your project. If you're simply linking already built executables/libraries against dynamic boost archives, the includes aren't necessary.

Comment: Did I download the wrong boost then? I downloaded the ZIP here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.58.0/boost_1_58_0.zip/download

Comment: The include files are in `boost_1_58_0/boost` after unzipping that archive.

Comment: I would try setting `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` to `e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/boost_1_58_0/boost`. This will find the right include directory.

Comment: As for your library directory, what you downloaded are the source files. To use boost in CMake, you need binaries that you can link against. You need to look up how to either build those binaries or download them from somewhere.

Comment: Same problem after `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` is correctly set. I'm not sure what you mean with your last comment.

Comment: I really wish there was just precompiled .lib files and .h files that simple-minded developers like me could use.

Comment: You might want to check in [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.58.0/) for precompiled binaries that might be compatible with your build. If it isn't there, there's not much you can do but build those binaries yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I finally got everything to the state I needed. What follows is essentially a description of how to get the magical libCGAL.dll and libCGAL.a (library files) that you want on Windows 7 with Code::Blocks.

1. I downloaded and installed CMake.
2. I downloaded and installed Boost 1.58.0, with the manual and GMP included (but not examples because I don't want to flub around with Qt). The destination was a folder without spaces.
3. I downloaded and installed CGAL-4.6. Again, destination was folder without spaces.
4. I added CodeBlocks\MingW\bin to my `PATH` environmental variable.
5. I went into the boost_1_58_0 folder, opened a command prompt, and typed `bootstrap gcc`, followed by `b2 --toolset=gcc`, all good. This seemed to build Boost into the stage\lib folder.
6. I made a new Code::Blocks project to test the Boost files. In the projects Build Options, I selected the root, added under Linker Settings a direct path to the `libboost_regex-mgw44-mt-1_58.a`, under Search Directories I added under Compiler the boost_1_58_0 folder, under Linker the boost_1_58_0\stage\lib folder. I then successfully compiled and ran the example regex program [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) (section 6).
7. I went into the CGAL-4.6 folder and opened a command prompt. I typed cmake-gui. I followed [this tutorial](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/setup-cgal-in-windows-7-step-by-step-tutorial/) to the letter, except that I (think) I chose "Specify native compilers" and pointed them to `mingw32-gcc.exe` and `mingw32-g++.exe` in the MingW folder (it might work with the first option if you've added MingW\bin to the path like you have to anyway, later)
8. After configuring and building correctly, a Code::Blocks project file was created, along with a Makefile. The Code::Blocks file was useless and wouldn't build correctly because it tried to run `make.exe` instead of `mingw32-make.exe`. I had no idea how to fix this, so I simply went to my Code::Blocks folder, opened a command prompt and typed `mingw32-make.exe -s -f <path-to-the-makefile> all`. It Make'd without problems.
9. Finally, I made a test project. Like in Step 6, I added ALL the non-debug libraries from Boost (blah-blah-NOT-d.a in stage/lib) and the libCGAL.dll.a library from CGAL-4.6\lib. I added also the Boost directories as in Step 6, and the CGAL-4.6\include directory too.
10. Super-finally, I compiled the example [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/introduction.html) without problems. Before running it. I had to move CGAL-4.6\bin\libCGAL.dll into the exe file folder, that is bin\Debug.

NOW THAT WAS PERFECTLY STRAIGHTFORWARD, WASN'T IT?!

If someone else gets stuck on this, throw a message and I can shoot you the actual files everyone wants: libCGAL.dll, libCGAL.dll.a, all the Boost library files and all the headers.